# How to Reorder Items in Flatlist/SectionList

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I have few questions:

In React Native

1) Do we have default reordering of items in Flatlist/SectionList, like we have for UITableview in iOS "moveRowAt sourceIndexPath:" method.

2) If No is the answer for the above question, could you please suggest me how to achieve reordering in react native.

I have tried the below package but its not smooth.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist

I came across this https://github.com/deanmcpherson/react-native-sortable-listview but as listview is deprecated, cannot go with this.